# Overlaying An Element Background over Its Own Border

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a style of heading that looks like this:
[Visual Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjXwf.png).

What I tried was using a class (.label-2) to describe the background colour and ::after (.label-2::after) to describe how the border should be placed. I think I lack a clear understanding of how pseudo-elements work as this had no effect whatsoever lol.

If anyone has any leading points to designs like this or can explain how I'd achieve this effect, that'd be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Edit:
Ideally, I would like to have a header (div) at the top. I would like to place this heading into this header.

Comment: I think this need a bit more information on the end result you'd like to acheive, There's lots of ways of doing this but not understanding the constrains or the approach makes it difficult to answer

Comment: @savageGoat I'm confused on what you mean; I've asked a pretty straight forward question. I would like an element that represents a label in which: 1. There is a border, 2. There is a "label" sitting on the bottom left of the border with a little bit of space to the left.

Comment: This actually explains the idea

Comment: Does the answer work for you?

Comment: @savageGoat Yup. It worked perfectly once I changed h4 to div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. I added a extra animation on hover

```css
.header-container {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.header {
  transform: translateY(50%);
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: min-width ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
.header:hover {
  min-width: 98%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="header">Text</div>
</div>
```